# What's the best way to share data among arbitrary numbers of instances in OpenGL (ES)?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, webgl, vbo

In my app, I have a transform hierarchy of objects. All the objects are instances of a single object, and there might be a large number of them. Any group in the hierarchy can have any number of instances or sub-groups.

Aside from the transforms, the instances can potentially be batched into a single draw call, and per-instance attributes can live in an attribute array with an instance stride.

I would like to specify the transforms for the objects in an efficient way, but I'm not sure the best approach. Here's what I've considered:

- **One matrix per instance, in an attribute array** with a divisor of 1.

  - This seems wasteful. If I have (say) 1000 objects in a single group, then I'll specify the same matrix 1000 times. When the parent transform changes, I'll also have to go update 1000 attributes instead of 1.
- Break into **multiple draw calls**, one for each leaf group, and specify the transform as a uniform at the start of each call.

  - This is less wasteful, but seems like it might be slower due to a larger number of draw calls. Groups with small numbers of instances might be inefficient due to poor batching.
  - This isn't possible in OpenGL ES anyway (WebGL specifically), since I'd need to either (a) offset the starting instance for each call, which AFAICT requires a call to `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance()`, or (b) build entirely separate attribute arrays for each group in the hierarchy, which also has more overhead + complexity.
- Use a **uniform array of transforms**, and specify a per-instance index into it

  - This seems untenable because it looks like the maximum size of uniform arrays is very small.
- Use a **uniform buffer object** to hold an array of transforms, and specify a per-instance index into the array

  - This seems better, though it still looks like the maximum array size isn't very large
- Use an **SSBO** to do the above

  - Looks like this isn't available in OpenGL ES 3.0.
- Something else?

What would be considered best practice for this task? Is there perhaps a method I haven't considered?

Comment: "*Any group in the hierarchy*" What is a "group" in this context? "*If I have (say) 1000 objects in a single group, then I'll specify the same matrix 1000 times.*" If they have the same matrix and come from the same mesh data (ie: instancing), then they are *the same object*. And there's no point in drawing the same object 1000 times.

Comment: A group is a set of objects plus a transform to apply to them; where "objects" means instances or more groups. A node in a scene graph, in other words. The instances are different because of per-instance attributes. One use case is cards with font glyphs— the instance attributes are the axis-aligned bounds of each glyph; a full matrix is not needed. A paragraph (group with hundreds of glyph instances) *could* have an arbitrary transform, however.

Comment: "*One use case is cards with font glyphs— the instance attributes are the axis-aligned bounds of each glyph; a full matrix is not needed*" Why would you use the same rendering system for text as you would for other things? These ought to be divided into different code. And you *definitely* shouldn't be rendering text with instances. But ultimately here, what seems clear is that a group transform is a different thing from an instance transform. So your renderer needs to acknowledge that.

Comment: This is really use-case dependent, just benchmark various approaches in a real-world scenario, alltough this sounds a bit like premature optimization based on how generic and arbitrary your description is. That being said, you can use floating point textures as a shim for read-only SSBOs.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have (say) 1000 objects in a single group, then I'll specify the same matrix 1000 times.

If you are repeating the same matrix you already have problems. Ultimately you need a unique matrix per instance because you need each instance to be transformed to a unique location on screen.

> When the parent transform changes, I'll also have to go update 1000 attributes instead of 1.

Yes, so? Matrices are small and very cheap to update.

It's a lot more efficient to update 1 matrix *per instance* on the CPU than perform a redundant tree of matrix fetches and calculations *per vertex* on the GPU.

> One matrix per instance, in an attribute array with a divisor of 1

If possible I'd try to avoid attributes and instance divisors for per instance data - this forces per-vertex refetches on a lot of GPUs because the fact that it's a per instance divisor isn't known at shader compile time.

If possible store what you need in an instance-count sized array in a uniform buffer or storage buffer, and index into that array using `gl_InstanceID` to fetch the matrix you need. UBO limits can be a problem, so if you need a lot of objects, then you'll need to partition the draws in chunks. (That said, benchmark this, it's going to be vendor dependent).

Comment: See my reply to a comment above; per-instance attributes are driving location. E.g. a 2D bound (4 floats instead of 16), or a position (2 or 3 instead of 16). Also I'm composing the tree CPU side, it's only broadcasting the composed matrix across many instances that I'm attempting to optimize.

I'm also considering putting indexed instance data into a 1D texture. How would you expect the performance of that to compare to the other options?

Comment: "across many instances", how many is "many" in terms of objects per frame? In the grand scheme of graphics data, matricies are tiny so even if you have 1000 objects it's only 16KB of data.

Comment: That'd be 64K if it's floats we're talking about :). Not that that's a huge weight either, but it'd be good to know what's most efficient in the limit. I could see ~dozens to a few thousand objects per "group"; maybe 10k objects on screen?